# Postfix google network is not reachable from server but its reachable with same configs on local

Tags: postfix, email-server, localhost

This is my main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
default_transport = smtp
relay_transport = smtp
inet_protocols = all
myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

Its the same on my local machine and on some server i am using. Also when applying `netstat -nltp  |grep master`
i have the same output on both server and local:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29325/master    
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      29325/master
```

and when sending email from local machine using:

```
echo 'test' | mail -s 'test' yamennassif89@gmail.com
```

its working 100% and i recieve email directly; but its not working when i try to do the same thing on the server.

any help would be appriciated.
thanks

update

#

forgot to add the error on the server from /var/log/mail.log

```
 connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be that the server provider had blocked all smtp communication. So they provided a gateway solution which fixed the issue. If you ended up here with the same situation contact your server company.